# ggplot2: create a lollipop chart in a specific order

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a lollipop chart with ggplot2 where my data is ordered by `Class`.

Here's my code so far:

```
FinalAA_class <- read_csv(file = "/cloud/project/Data/FinalAAs_classes.csv")  
FinalB <- slice(FinalAA_class, 1:17)
bFinalAA2 <- ggplot(FinalB, aes(x=EndAA, y=CountAA, fill=Class, colour=Class)) +  
  geom_point() + geom_segment( aes(x=EndAA, xend=EndAA, y=0, yend=CountAA)) +  
  xlab("Amino acid") + ylab("Count")
```

My data:

```
structure(list(Name = c("bitter", "bitter", "bitter", "bitter", 
"bitter", "bitter", "bitter", "bitter", "bitter", "bitter", "bitter", 
"bitter", "bitter", "bitter", "bitter", "bitter", "bitter"), 
    Class = c("Aliphatic", "Aliphatic", "Aliphatic", "Aliphatic", 
    "Aliphatic", "Acidic", "Acidic", "Acidic", "Aromatic", "Aromatic", 
    "Basic", "Basic", "Basic", "Polar", "Polar", "Polar", "Polar"
    ), EndAA = c("A", "I", "L", "V", "G", "D", "Q", "E", "W", 
    "F", "H", "K", "R", "T", "N", "S", "P"), CountAA = c(7, 17, 
    29, 41, 55, 5, 5, 13, 6, 57, 3, 7, 16, 1, 3, 4, 28)), class = 
    c("spec_tbl_df", 
    "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -17L), spec = 
    structure(list(
    cols = list(Name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Class = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), EndAA = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), CountAA = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

[image: Graph]

I want to order the graph so the lines appear in ascending order **starting with Acidic and ending with Polar**. (Same as the order it is in in the table).

Please see the hyperlink for the graph.

Comment: Hi glitterbox. Could you edit the question to share the data you're working with? If you type `dput(FinalB)` into the console and paste the result into a code block in your question, you'll have a much better chance of a good answer. Thanks.

Comment: check out `fct_inorder` from forcats/tidyverse packages to make the levels of a factor match the order in which they appear in the source data

Comment: @arvi1000 I have tried, but it's not changing anything.

Comment: The order of the lines is determined by the factor order (or can be set manually in `scale_x_discrete` or perhaps `scale_fill_discrete`). You are unlikely to receive a more useful answer unless you include usable data in your question. We can't use the data from an image, and Allan already has given a good way for you to share your data.

Comment: I don't understand how to add the data, unless what I've added now is correct?

Comment: Yes, glitterbox, that's what we were looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reorder the levels of `FinalB$EndAA` according to the order of the levels in `FinalB$Class`. You can do this with `fct_reorder` from `forcats`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

FinalB$EndAA <- fct_reorder(FinalB$EndAA, FinalB$CountAA)
FinalB$EndAA <- fct_reorder(FinalB$EndAA, FinalB$Class)
ggplot(FinalB, aes(x=EndAA, y=CountAA, fill=Class, colour=Class)) +  
  geom_point() + geom_segment( aes(x=EndAA, xend=EndAA, y=0, yend=CountAA)) +  
  xlab("Amino acid") + ylab("Count")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! Is there also a way to get them in ascending order, within their classes?

Comment: @glitterbox sure - just add an extra call to the other variable you want to order against. See my update.